# React: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Trying to get jest test to work for React project.  Installed babel and webpack, still giving this error:

Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: .../user.js: Unexpected token, expected "," 

export function user(toEnable: Bool, code: String = "") {
                             ^
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.15.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-css-modules-transform": "^2.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^4.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.10.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "~0.15.2",
    "classnames": "~2.2.5",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "numbro": "^1.11.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.7.2",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-clipboard.js": "~1.1.3",
    "react-datetime": "~2.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^2.0.0",
    "react-gmaps": "^1.5.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^2.0.8",
    "react-js-pagination": "~2.0.1",
    "react-loadable": "^5.4.0",
    "react-modal": "~3.4.4",
    "react-notifications": "^1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "~4.4.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "~4.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.3",
    "react-tabs": "^0.8.2",
    "redux": "~3.6.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "~2.1.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.6.0",
    "store2": "~2.3.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.0.8",
    "validator": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx}": [
      "prettier --write --trailing-comma es5 --semi false --print-width 160",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>__tests__/setup/setupEnzyme.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup/"
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

The test itself is just a simple one that just creates the component and fails on component creation because of this argument issue.  I've looked around and can't seem to find out how to fix this.

I'm certain this is an issue with ES6 + babel.  But I'm not sure how to fix it, everything I've tried does not fix it.  Everyone else's issue has been "real" syntax errors while this is just a named argument list.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is @flow dependency?

Comment: this is an existing working project, there doesn't appear to be @flow, I recently added eslint (airbnb) and prettier

Comment: is this because it's not a TS file, it's a js?

Comment: The error means that transpiler does not understand the parameter type definion. I see no flow and no typescript therefore the code is invalid.

Comment: Well yes, if it's Typescript then you can't use a JavaScript compiler.

Comment: ok, I will see if I can refactor this code to fix it, thanks

Comment: that was it, you guys are awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sulthan and JJJ - there is typescript mixed in the JS file.  removing all of the TS fixed the problem.